# Dependency Injection not working for websockets

Tags: java, spring, websocket

This is the piece of code I am facing issues with. When the post construct gets called..the source gets set .. But when I receive a message from server and the processBinaryMessage method gets called..the source turns out to be null.

I don't understand the problem...Any help is appreciated..

```
@ClientEndpoint
@Component
public class MyClientEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private Source Source;

    private boolean postConstructCalled = false;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        postConstructCalled = true;
        System.out.println("Post construct called ... ");
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
        SessionUtil.setSession(session);
        try {
            System.out.println("Checking the established connection........");
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Checking the connection...");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClientEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received string message in client: " + message);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void processBinaryMessage(byte[] bytes) {

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        byte[] type = new byte[3];
        byteBuffer.get(type);
        String msgType = new String(type);
        //System.out.println("Read type : " + msgType);

        if(msgType.compareTo("MAX") == 0) {
            int maxLimit =  byteBuffer.getInt();
            System.out.println("Read max blocks : " + maxLimit);
            ClientDataTransfer.setMaxTransferLimit(maxLimit);
        }
        else if(msgType.compareTo("NXT") == 0) {
            ClientDataTransfer.incMaxTransferLimit();
        }
        else if(msgType.compareTo("MAP") == 0) {
            int length =  byteBuffer.getInt();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            byteBuffer.get(data);
            source.getClientDataTransfer().addToDataRequestQueue(data);
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void processError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Closing connection to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Sreeja

Comment: Because you have 2 instances of this class. 1 spring managed and the other by your web socket library.

Comment: @Sreeja Mohan How are you using the *MyClientEndpoint*, is it a singleton  and used by multiple threads. From it's name, the usage appears to be restricted to single client side thread, though just wanted to confirm before I point out any issues with the posted code.

Comment: Hi @AnupamSaini, Yes it is singleton. Currently it is not a multi threaded application.

Comment: Hi @AnupamSaini, This is how I connect to the destination.                              public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  SpringApplication.run(SourceApplication.class, args);

  WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
  container.setDefaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout(-1);
  String uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/destination/";
  System.out.println("Connecting to " + uri);
  container.connectToServer(MyClientEndpoint.class, URI.create(uri));
                ...
 
 } I don't have much idea how this framework works internally...

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. Could you please let me know how could I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if its too late, but maybe it can help somebody.  I work with websockets recently and for solve that I take two approach, one of them was to on my client endpoint need to **extends Endpoint (javax.websocket.Endpoint)** I test that on wildfly 10.0.1.Final and works injecting with EJB and Inject (This using javaee-api v 7). Also in wildfly 14 and using javaee-api v8 I notice that extends endpoint is not mandatory for CDI injection, but ClientEndpoint and ServerEndpoint annotations  only are resolved in war module, hopes to help someone